# Swashbuckle does not display the API correctly

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Swashbuckle was used in my project, I followed the documentation, but at the end an error was displayed.
[image]

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
  {
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "ToDo API",
        Description = "A simple example ASP.NET Core Web API",
        TermsOfService = new Uri("https://example.com/terms"),
        Contact = new OpenApiContact
        {
            Name = "Shayne Boyer",
            Email = string.Empty,
            Url = new Uri("https://twitter.com/spboyer"),
        },
        License = new OpenApiLicense
        {
            Name = "Use under LICX",
            Url = new Uri("https://example.com/license"),
        }
    });
      });

    app.UseSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.SerializeAsV2 = true;
    });

app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    });
```

What did i do wrong? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there a detailed error description in console output of the application? What version of .NET and Swashbuckle do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered this problem before, and I can reproduce your problem, but I am not sure if this is your problem.

[image]

All configurations follow the official documentation:

[Get started with Swashbuckle and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Then the reason for this error is that you must specify the request method, you need to add [HttpGet], [HttpPost], etc. to the method, and you can view the API through Swagger UI,like this:

```
[ApiController]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("test")]
    public string Test()
    {
        return "Test";
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

If the above method cannot be solved, can you post your specific error message?

Comment: Yes, I have solved it, but thanks anyway!